# How can we prevent Skype accounts repeatedly going offline and online again?

Tags: proxy, connection, skype

Several of my Skype contacts appear to spend all day logging out and in again. I've asked them and they're not really doing anything, but my Skype app continually notifies me that they've just come online.

I get irritated with notifications about them, and they get irritated with notifications about me.

It appears to happen both with contacts who are using Windows and contacts who are using Ubuntu.

I am behind a corporate proxy, and so are (some?) of my contacts.

UPDATE: I know I can turn off notifications of others logins, but I'm more concerned with people seeing my logins popping up all day.

Comment: Are other programs going off-line all the time? E.g. if you start a program which establishes a connection and keeps that active (e.g. ssh, RDP) does that fail after a some time? ( SSH would give a timeout, RDP would show 'REconnecting' )

Comment: I face the same issue! Tried on Win 7, Win 8, Mac OS X - exists on all.

Comment: No, no other programs go offline, and no other network-related side-effects have been noticed. Many other people are aware of this issue with Skype.

Comment: You can turn off the notifications in Skype go to "Tools" -> "Notifications" -> and uncheck "Comes online" :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your status to Invisible.

I've done a test with a coworker and I can say that if you have your status set to Invisible while going online and offline, no one will receive a notification. I did test the other statuses (Online, Away, Do Not Disturb) and they all triggered notifications.